# Implementing multiple version flow in single Mule project

Tags: mulesoft, mule4

Trying to create a Mule project with support for multiple version endpoints. To begin with I have started with two API specification with same endpoints but with different `version`.

1. hello-world-v1.raml (version: 1, GET /hello)
2. hello-world-v2.raml (version: 2, GET /hello)

Then used these both RAML files to create Mule project. By default it created two Listeners on different port. But I want to start app in single server and port but go to flow based version of path e.g.

- https://www.custom-greetings.com/api/v1/hello will server based on first RAML specification whereas
- https://www.custom-greetings.com/api/v2/hello will server based on second RAML specification

The reason I want to have Mule project with both version is so that my client can use same domain instead of
`https://www.custom-greetings-v1.com` vs `https://www.custom-greetings-v2.com`

I am pretty sure there is efficient way to do this but not finding any related example or guidance.

Any help/pointer is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying to a standalone Mule server you can move the HTTP Listener configuration to a [Mule Domain](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/shared-resources) and share it with both applications. That way both listen to the same port but in different URI paths. This method can not be used in [CloudHub](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/cloudhub) nor [Runtime Fabric](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-fabric/1.7/) deployments because they don't support domains.

Another alternative would be to combine manually both RAMLs into a single one and create a single application with a single HTTP Listener for both APIs. This alternative will be compatible with CloudHub and Runtime Fabric.

Yet another option would be to put a load balancer in front of both applications. For a standalone Mule installation you need to provide your own load balancer. CloudHub provides a feature called [Dedicated Load Balancer](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/cloudhub-dedicated-load-balancer) to do this. Runtime Fabric uses Kubernetes ingress mechanism.